# Can I register multiple schema files in config/lighthouse.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

Can I register multiple schema files in config/lighthouse.php

In config/lighthouse.php

```
'schema' => [
    'register' => base_path('graphql/schema.graphql'),
],
```

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use [schema imports](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/digging-deeper/schema-organisation.html).

Suppose you created your schema files likes this:

```
graphql/
|-- schema.graphql
|-- user.graphql
```

Lighthouse reads your schema from a single entrypoint, in this case `schema.graphql`.
You can import other schema files from there to split up your schema into multiple files.

```
type Query {
  user: User
}

#import user.graphql
```

Imports always begin on a separate line with `#import`, followed by the relative path
to the imported file. The contents of `user.graphql` are pasted in the final schema.

```
type Query {
  user: User
}

type User {
    name: String!
}
```

The import statements are followed recursively, so it is easy to organize even the most complex of schemas.

You can also import multiple files using wildcard import syntax.
For example, if you have your schema files like this:

```
graphql/
  |-- schema.graphql
  |-- post/
    |-- post.graphql
    |-- category.graphql
```

Instead of naming each individual file, you can import multiple files that matches a pattern.
It will be loaded using PHP's [glob function](http://php.net/manual/function.glob.php).

```
#import post/*.graphql
```

Comment: It helps a lot, bro. Thanks

Comment: @Jonathan remember to mark answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this one looking for a solution to my problem where the imports did not work, even though they were on their own seperate line. Turns out my line separator was set to CR (classic macOS). So check your line separator settings.